# ModelState error The value '1/1/2015' is not valid for Date Mvc5 asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem : my site is developed to work with different cultures (mainly Arabic and English) when the user select the culture "ar-sa" (from icon in the template) and try to save data into database i always get error that The value '1/1/2015' is not valid for Date. for all dates i try to add date in different format like (21/09/17 23:39:35 PM) or (14/03/14 06:14:34 ص) or even i try to

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(model.Birth_Date, @"d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I read some articals about the problem but no sense

```
<system.web>     
       <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="Auto" culture="Auto" />
    </system.web>
```

this is my code

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "System_UserID,FirstNameAr,NameShortcut,Gender,Religion,Birth_Date,Birth_Place")] System_User system_User)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.System_User.Add(system_User);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


            return View(system_User);
        }
```

and

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birth_Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birth_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birth_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```